# how to find similar Ids inside a parent ID with Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given the followng HTML, I need to count the number of note_record[0-9] ids with in the note_table21 id.  How would I do this with jquery? NOTE: the number at the end of the note_record id will be generated dynamically.  I need some kind of regex but I'm too much of a jquery noob to get it right

```
<table id="note_table21" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
 <tbody>
    <tr id="note_record259">...</tr>
    <tr id="note_record260">...</tr>
    <tr id="note_record261">...</tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Would there ever be a reason to not have an id of note_recordxxx inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [*starts with*](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) (`^=`) selector to test the beginning of an attribute:

```
$(document).find("#note_table21 tr[id^=note_record]").length;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7uyaW/

Answer (score 2):

To get the count of `tr` in `note_table21` whose ids start with `note_record`:

```
var count = $("#note_table21 tr[id^=note_record]").length
```

What does the trick here is the [Attribute Starts With selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

**Update**

That said, you should change your document structure to look like this:

```
<table class="note_table" data-id="21" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
 <tbody>
    <tr class="note_record" data-id="259">...</tr>
    <tr class="note_record" data-id="260">...</tr>
    <tr class="note_record" data-id="261">...</tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Then you'd have these script snippets to help you:

```
///gets the rows in a variable
var $rows = $(".note_table tr.note_record]");

//gets the count
var count = $rows.length;

//iterate through the rows, alerting the id of each row:
$rows.each(function(index, row){
    var id = $(row).data("id");
    alert(id);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS selector for children.

```
$("#note_table21 > #note_record259")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#note_table21 tbody tr[id*='note_record']").length;
});
```